# Encoding hashed trackID data in sequence models

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, categorical-data, feature-selection, sequential-pattern-mining

I have a sequential dataset consisting of a history of sequential media playback data for every user, where each playback has a "trackID" as a feature, corresponding to a hash ID of the song / track that was played during the playback. I want to use this sequential data in sequential models like RNN, LSTM, or Seq2Seq, however I do not want to use the "trackID" feature, since it is inherently not predictive for my task (trackID has a very high cardinality, as you can imagine, since there are millions of tracks / songs) yet the fact that there might be multiple "repeat" playbacks with the same trackID in a sequence or that some playbacks have unique trackID's in the sequence, both of which are definitely important for my prediction task. How then can I encode this information in my dataset, that show that some tracks might be repeated in future playbacks, or there might be new unseen tracks in playbacks? However, I don't want to use the trackID particularly, since they are hash ID's and have very high cardinality, which do not have any inherent important information or relevance to the task.

Comment: What about using reuse distance as a feature instead of trackID to detect repetition or uniqueness of tracks in sequence?